# How does one write a type-assertion function to check whether all containers in an array are in a certain state?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types, variadic-tuple-types

I'm working with a library that models results to asynchronous operations in a way similar to the following:

```
type Success<TData> = { status: 'success', data: TData }; 
type Loading = { status: 'loading' }
type Query<TData> = Success<TData> | Loading
```

In the situation where one is dealing with multiple `Query` objects it would be convenient to be able to check that they're all `Success` objects with one function-call, eg:

```
const a = useFetchA() // Query<A>
const b = useFetchB() // Query<B>

if (isAllSuccess([a,b])) {
  // in here:
  // a is Success<A>
  // b is Success<B>
}
```

I've been trying to write such a function, but I'm quite confused as to why TypeScript does not accept the predicate:

```
type Success<T> = {status: 'success', data: T}
type Loading = {status: 'loading'}
type Query<T> = Success<T> | Loading

const isAllSuccess = <T extends Array<Query<any>>>(
  queries: readonly [...T]
): queries is { [I in keyof T]: Success<T[I]> } => {
//                 ^ A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
//                     Type '{ [I in keyof T]: Success<T[I]>; }' is not assignable to type 'readonly [...T]'.
//                       Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer.(2677)
  if (queries.length === 0) return false;
  return queries.every((q) => q.status === "success");
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that the `queries` is already `T` and `T` can't be switched to `{ [I in keyof T]: Success<T[I]> }`. I would suggest accepting a `T`, but accepting `queries` as `queries: Query<any>[]`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrgYwRAzigPAFQHxQLxQDeKwAhsHCgFxQDkKiyatANFACbmk2YC+AUKEhQAMgHtS7AJYA7AOb4iJcpRq0ANhOnzaAodACKcCACcQWXAXhJUGHFAA+orbLn9+CMTJJQpKAILq6tZMKIpYUBAAHsAQMuxhRqbmpDIg2ADaALrYABQAjsYmUqg0SWboqenZUACUNIWmJWF+RFAZAJK+MlAA1hAgYgBmUJhZNCG2WJ05ULz4uIT8UL4jBUXNAHTqcXLAABb4eAQADLVQJhAUJj1DpOooEADcyxdXcDdQjcWomxAAbslcgVznhcPlNsoKGFjgQAEQMGxoOG1F68F4eLw+bhQcrmEjFeSWNpQ1R0TSSVy0OaY7zAKAAIzKRXMMjgAFsGaZiYQoKTqHREaFWBwuDQAIw0-hSNZ+QLBRi2XIZUgsBlZWrnJavTx0qCkSUEUgvFYAelNKxWAD0APz8ARAA)?

Comment: No, I mean't something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5xjBw)

Comment: That's interesting. `arr[0]` is typed correctly inside the conditional, even though `a` is not.

Comment: Yes, this is the current limitation in typescript with the type guards.